# Node.app - runs locally, deploys correctly but fails to work

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

i'm trying to deploy my node app on heroku.

This app works fine localy, and is properly pushed on heroku.

However, whenever I try to reach the URL, the browsers displays:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again       in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details
```

At first, I thought that was because I didn't pay attention the port I was listening to (I don't really understand how Heroku processes and if the port is important) so I copied the same code as they did in their *Getting started...*:

```
    port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.listen(port, function() {
console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

my package.json is very basic :

```
   {

"name":"Radiorev",
"version":"0.0.1",
"dependencies":{

    "express":"3.3.5",
    "socket.io":"0.9.16"
}
  }
```

Help!

By the way when I type heroku log, my cmd tools displays something quite unreadable... with zero line breaks.

Comment: what exactly does `heroku logs --app {appname}` output?

Answer (score 5):

#### 1

Heroku does not support websockets, so try turning it off

```
// assuming io is the Socket.IO server object
io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
```

as per [Using Socket.IO with Node.js on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku)

#### 2

update: H14 - is `Error H14 (No web processes running)`

try adding Procfile with following contents:

`web: node server.js`

Comment: That looked promising ... however, it still doesn't work :( 

I'm having the H14 error when I do Heroku logs

Comment: heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=radiorev.herokuapp.com fwd="88.181.11.
146" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: I already added a Profile. I followed all the steps on heroku's website. My app is named app.js so I added : 

web: node app.js

Comment: @user2249582 just to clarify its Procfile, not Profile

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be that you scaled your web dynos to 0, so there's no one to run the server. Try running:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

(Reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running)

Comment: Thanks Vitor, this one worked in my case. run **heroku ps** after you run the scale web